# Will hair that fall along with dandruff regrow?

Tags: hair, dandruff

I occasionally brush my fingers through my hair, and can sometimes feel dandruff stuck in my hair (not on my scalp). When I gently, as in really carefully and gently, remove these dandruff, I often see them come out with hair attached to them. Most of the time it's one or two strands of hair for each dandruff grain/bit. I'm just wondering whether this is a permanent loss of hair, and therefore whether the hair will regrow?